# How can I solve these equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving

I can't figure it out, please help :S

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
2x + 2xz &=& 0\\
-2y + 2yz &=& 0\\
x^2 + y^2 &=& 4
\end{array}$$
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$2x(z+1)=0\iff x=0\ \text{or}\ z=-1,$$
$$2y(-1+z)=0\iff y=0\ \text{or}\ z=1,$$
$$x^2+y^2=4.$$

1) When $x=0\ \text{and}\ y=0$, these don't satisfy the last equation.

2) When $x=0\ \text{and}\ z=1$, $y=\pm 2$.

3) When $z=-1\ \text{and}\ y=0$, $x=\pm 2$.

4) There is no $z$ such that $z=-1\ \text{and}\ z=1$.

As a result, you'll have
$$(x,y,z)=(0,\pm2,1),(\pm2, 0,-1).$$

Comment: Thank you, it really helped! I thought there was a more simple result but now I see there is not any :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Grobi there is discrete possible values of  variables to satisfy all condition

Answer (score 1):

Szuppose that $x=0$. Then $y=\pm 2$, hence $z=1$. Otherwise we may assume that $x\neq 0$. Then $z=-1$ by the first equation, and $y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Factor the first two.  That gives four easy solutions, two with $x=0$ and two with $y=0$  Now assume $x,y \neq 0$  Then find a contradiction because each of the first two require a different value of $z$

Answer (score 0):

ok so you have

$x(1+z)=0$

$y(z-1)=0$

$x^2+y^2=4$

now clearly it can't be both $x$ and $y$ be zero,could you say something about roots? for example from first two,what if $z=-1$? in this case what is $y$?

what if $x=0$? and

$(z=1)$?